# Long format table - calculation depending on row position

Tags: r

The dataset `abweichung`i set up in long format. Each row corresponds to a calculation. The column `Berechnung` contains original value - "EconoMe Original" and 50 modifications - "Berechnung". I would like to calculate the change (in %) between the "EconoMe original"  and  "Berechnung" and save the output in a nwe column in the dataset.

The problem is that I have multiple "Econome original" values, each with 50 modifications. These are merged together in a long format data table. **How can i code the calculation?**

I tried writting an function, but it has not worked. I am new to R, but I am sure this has an easy solution.

Comment: can u show the code u used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, set up a variable to record the case number (i.e. each block starting with an 'EconoMe'), then group by the case number, and calculate the percentage difference for each group...

```
library(dplyr)
abweichung <- abweichung %>% mutate(Case=cumsum(Berechnung=="EconoMe original")) %>% 
            group_by(Case) %>% 
            mutate(Differenz=100*(NK/NK[Berechnung=="EconoMe original"]-1))
```